# Instantiation error - name is already in use

Tags: php, class, object

I'm using a library and instantiating objects like so:

```
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Constants;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Services;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types;

use \DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Services;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Enums;
```

which results in an error:

`Fatal error: Cannot use DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Services as Services because the name is already in use in ...`

However if I use them in separate php files, they work fine. What should I change here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could give them an alias like so:

```
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Services as ServicesOne;

use \DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Services as ServicesTwo;
```

Comment: and oned because it's correct, though you should try to give them more meaningful names for easier maintain- and readability.